# CSS border-radius and overflow hidden on container makes content seep through by 1 px

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/uq2018xv/3/

```css
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container>img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container>span {
  background: #2b2b2c;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0pt 0 2pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1593005510329-8a4035a7238f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80">
  <span>EDIT</span>
</div>
```

The content seeps through at the bottom by 1px. Is there a way to fix this to make it look cleaner?

[image]

Comment: you could add `margin-bottom: -1px;` into the "EDIT span" style

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman that didn't work as the span is inside the container too. It still shows the same line.

Comment: I think a box-sizing to your `.container` should do it - `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @DeeStarks I tired it but it didn't work. But I found a solution using `clip-path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. By setting:

```
clip-path: inset(0px 0px HEIGHT_OF_EDIT_SPAN 0px);
```

on the image.

where HEIGHT_OF_EDIT_SPAN is the height of the EDIT span at the bottom.

So it clips the image at the bottom but still keeps the image centered.